# Bar driagram (e.g. with ggplot2) with multiple y value variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, diagram

I would like to create a diagram in R looking like this (created in excel)

[image]

the excel table looks like this:

[image]

Could you please help me with creating a data frame and the code for example with ggplot to create such a diagram in R?

Thank you in advance!

ggplot2, fill argument

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

We don't have your data, so I created some data (see below). First you should transform your data to a longer format using `pivot_longer` after that you can use `geom_col` with `position_dodge` to create a dodged barplot like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes) # excel theme
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -class) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = class)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), width = 0.5) +
  theme_excel_new() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Data used:

```
df <- data.frame(class = c("CD I", "CD II", "CD III", "No compl."),
                 DP = c(3,3,4,13),
                 PD = c(1,5,2,10),
                 DPPHR = c(1,0,0,9),
                 SP = c(0,0,0,0),
                 TP = c(0,2,1,0))
```